# How to compare two strings without case sensitivity?

Tags: c

I have a code:

```
int main()
{
    printf("to exit the program type \"exit\":");
    char s[40];
    scanf("%s",s);
    if(strcmp(s,"exit")==0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int n;
        printf("wrong");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to when I enter "ExIt" it works.
how can i change that?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **tolower()** in C, but it works for char, so maybe you need to itterate over s string and putting every char to lower case.

Comment: Without explaining the shortcomings this is *dangerous advice* because it fails for non-English alphabet languages. In general you **should not** implement case-insensitive comparison by converting the characters. Use a proper case-insensitive compare instead.

Comment: oh, you're right, i just thought the mate works on a simple code and maybe just a hint will be useful, but i hope he sees your comment

Answer (score -1):

use `stricmp` instead of `strcmp`.

More letters to hit 30

Comment: `stricmp()` is not defined by the C Standard, or even POSIX

Comment: `stricmp` is a Visual Studio library.  I don't think it's standard C.  There's strcasecmp on Linux.

Comment: Haha - it's been 25 years + Didn't know that!